# JawsDB stuck on "BACKING-UP"

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have a website on Heroku that uses JawsDB MySQL.  The app is crashing with "ConnectionRefused."  When I try to log into the database directly through MySQL Workbench, it returns "unable to connect to localhost," suggesting to ensure that MySQL is running on the amazonaws.com address, that port 3306 is open, and that the username has rights with the right password.

When I go to the JawsDB settings page, the Server Status indicates the "Status" is "BACKING-UP."  It's been that way for hours.

Is this something that Heroku needs to fix?  Amazon?  How do I get it unstuck?  I'd dump the whole thing and start a new database except I would need to get a backup of my data...which I can't get because I can't access the database.

Comment: You were NOT ALONE! This is happening to us too (at this time of writing) and our public apps are down because of this. Our JawsDB MySQL is completely down, cannot connect from our back-end components, nor from SQLClient tool, nor from Heroku dashboard itself ("Connection Failed"). There is NO single explanation nor email from JawsDB vendor explaining this fatal failure.  *UPDATE 6:30 pm = After waiting 24 hours, now we could visit our JawsDB dashboard, but still down with status = "DELETING" ... (expected: Available). Are we this hopeless?

Comment: You can find JawsDB servers status and their SUPPORT EMAIL (shows at the page) at the following link to contact them directly: https://www.jawsdb.com/status/

Comment: I contacted Heroku who then contacted JawsDB.  They did magic in the background to move my DB to an alternative location on Amazon, and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**HACKERS BEWARE**

This issue could be related to recent Heroku security breach on April 7 - April 13, 2022 where many Heroku accounts and our applications were compromised! The following is statement from Salesforce (Heroku) Security Team (5/4/2022):

"*... Our investigation also revealed that the same compromised token was leveraged to gain access to a database and exfiltrate the hashed and salted passwords for customers’ user accounts. For this reason, Salesforce is ensuring all Heroku user passwords are reset and potentially affected credentials are refreshed. We have rotated internal Heroku credentials and put additional detections in place. We are continuing to investigate the source of the token compromise.*"

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Heroku who then contacted JawsDB. They did magic in the background to move my DB to an alternative location on Amazon, and it was fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).